# Moving image in certain area by touch using CGAffineTransformTranslate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

I want to move the image in the certain area of screen. I don't want to mess with frame, because it causes trouble with collision behavior later on. I got this code so far.I don't know how to use touch  Thanks for help

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //CGPoint svpt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.playerMove];
    CGRect frame = [self.playerMove frame];
    CGAffineTransform CGAT = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGAT = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAT, MIN(MAX(frame.origin.x, -10), 240), MIN(MAX(frame.origin.y, 430), 430));
    self.playerMove.transform = CGAT;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pan gesture recognizer.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[self.playerMove addGestureRecognizer:gr];
self.playerMove.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Then later...

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gr {

    if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        UIView *view = gr.view;
        CGPoint translation = [gr translationInView:view];
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(view.transform, translation.x, translation.y);
        [gr setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:view];
    }
}
```

Comment: The image isn't moving...I called first two lines of code in viewDidLoad and the use the handlePan method
And also, how to set the boundaries for area I want to move image in??

Comment: Hmm. I just tested, and while imperfect. This works for me.  Please make sure that the playerMove view has userInteractionEnabled = YES.

Comment: Edited the answer to add reminder about userInteractionEnabled, also improved the pan code to reset the translation state between recognitions.

Comment: Can you write me your mail address, I will send you a project, it's just a few lines of code, if you can look at it.thanks for reply

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com, then paste the link here.  i should be able to get to it before end of day today.

Comment: Couldn't get that link to work.  Here's a discardable email address: dhjv.3.nospamdan@spamgourmet.com

Comment: I ran your code, and it does not match my advice.  When I change it to match my advice, it works.  1) in your view did load.  create the gesture recognizer, add it to the view and set user interaction enabled=YES.  2) in handlePan, you must use the gesture recognizer passed as a parameter.  Do not allocate a new one.  Just copy the method that's in the answer.  It works.  Finally, the dropCoin and dropHammer methods interfere with the drag events.  I just put a return; as the first line of those methods to prove the drag worked.